# "No value has been specified for property 'aptOptions.processorpath'" problem

Tags: android, android-studio

when I upgrade the android studio from 3.3 to 3.4. and trying to rebuild the project, facing "No value has been specified for property 'adoptions.processorpath " problem

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `gradle-apt-plugin` to latest one. 
i.e. `classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.21"`